# How to iterate through URL in Python

Tags: python, loops

I have the following base url that I would like to iterate:

```
http://www.blabla.com/?mode_id=1
```

Basically, I would like Python for loop to iterate through id=1 like this:

```
http://www.blabla.com/?mode_id=1

http://www.blabla.com/?mode_id=2

http://www.blabla.com/?mode_id=3

http://www.blabla.com/?mode_id=4, etc.
```

I tried with my loop below, but it does not work:

```
for i in range(0, 200,1):
url = 'http://www.blabla.com/?mode_id= + str(i)'
driver.get(url)
```

How can I make it run properly? Thank you

Comment: Place str(i) outside the string: url = 'http://www.blabla.com/?mode_id=' + str(i)

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
for i in range(200):
    url = 'http://www.blabla.com/?mode_id={}'.format(i)
    driver.get(url)
```

Remarks:

- If you're going to start iterating one by one from zero, you can just use `range(200)`, no need for the rest of arguments.
- You should avoid concatenating strings in Python. There are better ways, like `format` (as per my example).
- Make sure your indentation is correct.